# Understand Java IO

Tags: java

I am still a newbie java programmer. I was learning about Java IO and noticed that in the book as well as in the online tutorials they donot talk about scanner class. They always mention, creating input/output stream reader objects and use them to read or write.

I am very familiar with scanner class and after reading I started to think may be scanner is not the right way to read console input/files in java.

Please clarify my doubt and if you could point me to an easy to understand tutorial, it will be great. I have already looked up oracle docs and other popular websites. Read Herbert schildt's book & the awful head first java book (barf..barf)

Comment: If I recall correctly, Scanner is most suitable for reading input that is in human-readable form (e.g. I want 5 numbers from System.in entered by a user, then a line of text, then two decimal numbers). (correct me if I'm wrong)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scanner class is a special file reader which is optimized for reading text files. If you want to read other file types the scanner class is not optimal. 
A good overview can be found here [java i/o](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/index.html). The summary form there:

> The java.io package contains many classes that your programs can use to read and write data. Most of the classes implement sequential access streams. The sequential access streams can be divided into two groups: those that read and write bytes and those that read and write Unicode characters. Each sequential access stream has a speciality, such as reading from or writing to a file, filtering data as its read or written, or serializing an object.

After reading this, you should look into [Apache Commons I/O](http://commons.apache.org/io/) which give you some handy utility classes for i/o.

Answer (score 1):

You to understand that a) a lot of material about Java was written years ago and Scanner is relatively recent. b) Scanner the right tool in some situations but you can use raw stream for binary or readers for text in all situations.

As you suspect Scanner is the right choice for simple text documents.

You have evaluate the material you are reading and give it context (like how old is it) There isn't any tutorial which will help you with that. ;)

Comment: One of my pet hates is StringBuffer. An alternative, StringBuilder, was provided and recommended in Java 5.0 (2004) but you still people using it even now. :P

Comment: `Scanner` has been there since about 2004, which is more than half the lifetime of Java.

Comment: @EJP good point though new libraries take a long time to become the standard way of doing things.

Answer (score 0):

Java io package supports *byte* level and *character* level operations. Both can be done in *streamed* or *buffered* fashion done. Examples about these IO types can be found [here](https://github.com/amjadmajid/java).

A Scanner object is useful for breaking down formatted input into tokens and translating individual tokens according to their data type.
Example about the [Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html)